# Remotely Reset Managed Device as if Just Provisioned

Tags: android-management-api

Is there a way to remotely "reset" a company owned device to the "just finished setup" state? Some of our users find a way to log into different systems (like Samsung and Google accounts for S series devices) and we want a way to reset the device to a "guaranteed clean state". We don't mind losing any data on the device, because everything either already syncs up to the cloud, or were just temporary files.

To clarify, I want the device to stay enrolled, just clear out any user data that accumulated over time on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to remotely reset a company-owned device but the device will be unenrolled and return to the out-of-box experience. This can typically be done through a web-based console or management portal provided by the device management software vendor. To perform a remote or reset, you will typically need to have administrative access to the device management console and the necessary permissions to perform the operation.

In Android Management API, if you can call the [enterprises.devices.delete](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete) method to reset a device to a “guaranteed clean state”, once you initiate a reset or wipe command, the device will typically be erased of all data and restored to its default or unenroll state, just as it was first taken out of the box.